# How to determine Big O performance by looking at for loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have just begun learning about Big O Notation and honestly I don't think I have the hang of it, and I am not quite sure how to determine the O() performance by just looking at for loops. I have listed a few examples and then some of the answers that I think are correct! Please let me know if they are wrong and any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

```
for (int i = 0; i <1000; i++) {
        count ++;
```

I believe this would be O(n), because nothing else is going on in the for loop except constant time printing. We iterate 'n' times, or in this case 1000?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
       count ++;
```

Would this one have an O(n^2) because the loops are nested and it iterates n twice, n*n?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for( int j = i; j < n; j++)
       count++;
```

Is this one another O(n^2) but in the worst case? Or is this O(n log n)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big-O notation is supposed to be a guide to help the user understand how the runtime increases with input.

For the first example, the loop runs exactly 1000 times no matter what `n` is, thus it is `O(1000) = O(1)` time.

For the second example, the nested loop runs `n` times for every time the outer loop runs, which runs `n` times. This is a total of `n*n = n^2` operations. Thus the number of operations increases proportional to the square of `n`, thus we say it is `O(n^2)`.

For the third example, it is still `O(n^2)`. This is because Big-O notation ignores constants in the exact formula of the time complexity. If you calculate the number of times `j` runs as `i` increases, you get this pattern.

```
i: 0  1   2   3 ...
j: n n-1 n-2 n-3 ...
```

In total, the number of operations is around `1/2 n^2`. Since Big-O notation ignores constants this is still `O(n^2)`